# Can't seem to correctly add Helix Toolkit to my C# (Visual Studio Express 2012) project

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, helix-3d-toolkit

I've been trying to add a HelixViewport3D to my WPF application and keep failing spectacularly  - I have managed to add references to some precompiled .dll's for .NET-4.5 from [here](https://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/76036), but then I still cannot add the desired element to the GUI.

Here's a screenshot which hopefully says everything you need to know: [image]

After dragging the HelixToolkit.Wpf.dll file into the toolbox, and then trying to add it from there, this is what happens: [image] to which no amount of "OK"-ing, restarting, or furiously mashing the keyboard will fix the problem

Comment: What is your question?  Do you get a proper error message?

Comment: Install Helix from Nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/HelixToolkit

Comment: Installing the nuGet creates this error:Install-Package : `You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  HelixToolkit
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`

Comment: I am aware that this means that the nuGet package is not available for .NET4.5 - but - my original download had 4.5 folder where my DLLs have come from

Comment: @PhilipPittle The specific error is that I can't add any toolbox elements or XML elements that Helix Toolkit is supposed to come with - I can, however, compile code `using HelixToolkit` without a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unblock the zip file you downloaded before adding a reference to the dll. The VS designer fails due to the security restrictions added to files downloaded from the internet.